# ArgumentNullException with Nullable Types, Text.Json and EF Core

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, entity-framework-core, nullable-reference-types

After about 15 hours of troubleshooting, I am just so confused at what is happening, and no longer sure what the real issue is, so I plead for any suggestions or hints you may have.

I have a ASP.NET Core project using .NET 5, EntityFramework Core, Text.Json and Nullable Reference Types. When my models have a parameterless constructor, everything seems to work fine, but if I try to create a parameterized constructor I start having issues.

When requesting a list of entries, it seems fine, but request a single entry returns an `ArgumentNullException`. The problem seems to come from a lack of *parameterless constructor*, but this introduces problems with the nonnullable properties.

After having tried to isolate the problem, it still appears when all navigational properties is removed, so the problem appears in the following basic application.
As `Id`, `Name` and `IsComplete` are nonnullable, I understand that they should be in a parameterized constructor, as mentioned in [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/nullable-reference-types):

> When nullable reference types are enabled, the C# compiler emits warnings for any uninitialized non-nullable property, as these would contain null. As a result, the following, common way of writing entity types cannot be used:

```
public class CustomerWithWarning
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    // Generates CS8618, uninitialized non-nullable property:
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

> Constructor binding is a useful technique to ensure that your non-nullable properties are initialized:

```
public class CustomerWithConstructorBinding
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public CustomerWithConstructorBinding(string name)
    {
        Name = name;
    }
}
```

Following is included most of the (relevant) code:
Error-message and stack-trace at bottom:

**TodoItem.cs** (not working):

```
using System.Text.Json.Serialization;

namespace TodoApi.Models
{
    public class TodoItem
    {
        [JsonConstructor]
        public TodoItem(long id, string name, bool isComplete)
        {
            (Id, Name, IsComplete) = (id, name, isComplete);
        }
        public long Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public bool IsComplete { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**TodoItem.cs** (working, but undesirable):

```
using System.Text.Json.Serialization;

namespace TodoApi.Models
{
    public class TodoItem
    {
        publicTodoItem()
        {
        }
        [JsonConstructor]
        public TodoItem(long id, string name, bool isComplete)
        {
            (Id, Name, IsComplete) = (id, name, isComplete);
        }
        public long Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public bool IsComplete { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**TodoItemsController.cs** (auto-generated):

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using TodoApi.Models;

namespace TodoApi.Controllers
{
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    public class TodoItemsController : ControllerBase
    {
        private readonly TodoContext _context;

        public TodoItemsController(TodoContext context)
        {
            _context = context;
        }

        // GET: api/TodoItems
        [HttpGet]
        public async Task<ActionResult<IEnumerable<TodoItem>>> GetTodoItems()
        {
            return await _context.TodoItems.ToListAsync();
        }

        // GET: api/TodoItems/5
        [HttpGet("{id}")]
        public async Task<ActionResult<TodoItem>> GetTodoItem(long id)
        {
            var todoItem = await _context.TodoItems.FindAsync(id);

            if (todoItem == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            return todoItem;
        }
    }
}
```

**TodoContext.cs**:

```
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

namespace TodoApi.Models
{
    public class TodoContext : DbContext
    {
        public TodoContext(DbContextOptions<TodoContext> options)
            : base(options)
        {
        }

        public DbSet<TodoItem> TodoItems { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**Startup.cs**:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;

using System.Text.Json.Serialization;

using TodoApi.Models;

namespace TodoApi
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {

            services.AddControllers();
            
            services.AddMvc().AddJsonOptions(
                opt => opt.JsonSerializerOptions.ReferenceHandler = ReferenceHandler.Preserve
            );

            services.AddDbContext<TodoContext>(opt =>
                {
                    opt.UseNpgsql(string.Format(
                        "host={0};port={1};database={2};username={3};password={4}",
                        "localhost",
                        "5432",
                        "databaseNameHere",
                        "databaseUsername",
                        "databasePassword"));
                    opt.UseLazyLoadingProxies();
                }
                );
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }

            app.UseHttpsRedirection();

            app.UseRouting();

            app.UseAuthorization();

            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllers();
            });
        }
    }
}
```

**Error-message:**

> An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.
> ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'obj')
> System.OrdinalIgnoreCaseComparer.GetHashCode(string obj)

**Stack-trace:**

> fail: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware[1]
> An unhandled exception has occurred while executing the request.
> System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'obj')
> at System.OrdinalIgnoreCaseComparer.GetHashCode(String obj)
> at System.Text.Json.JsonClassInfo.ParameterLookupKey.GetHashCode()
> at System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2.FindValue(TKey key) at System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2.TryGetValue(TKey key, TValue& value)
> at System.Text.Json.JsonClassInfo.InitializeConstructorParameters(ConstructorInfo constructorInfo)
> at System.Text.Json.JsonClassInfo..ctor(Type type, JsonSerializerOptions options)
> at System.Text.Json.JsonSerializerOptions.GetOrAddClass(Type type)
> at System.Text.Json.JsonSerializerOptions.GetOrAddClassForRootType(Type type)
> at System.Text.Json.WriteStack.Initialize(Type type, JsonSerializerOptions options, Boolean supportContinuation)
> at System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.WriteAsyncCore[TValue](Stream utf8Json, TValue value, Type inputType, JsonSerializerOptions options, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Formatters.SystemTextJsonOutputFormatter.WriteResponseBodyAsync(OutputFormatterWriteContext context, Encoding selectedEncoding)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.g__Awaited|29_0[TFilter,TFilterAsync](ResourceInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isComple
> ted)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Rethrow(ResultExecutedContextSealed context)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.ResultNext[TFilter,TFilterAsync](State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.InvokeResultFilters()
> --- End of stack trace from previous location ---
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.g__Awaited|24_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Rethrow(ResourceExecutedContextSealed context)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.g__Awaited|19_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.g__Awaited|17_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task task, IDisposable scope)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware.g__AwaitRequestTask|6_0(Endpoint endpoint, Task requestTask, ILogger logger)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.AuthorizationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)

If there's any missing details, please let me know! I've tried to include everything I can think of as relevant.

Comment: Fun-fact: Entity Framework / EF Core does _not_ play-nice with immutability and custom entity class ctors. You'll have to learn to live with mutable and maybe-null-but-we-dont-know-for-sure properties in entity objects :( - My workaround in my projects is to wrap EF's _petulant_ objects in my own immutable wrappers.

Comment: @zaggler, well... I can't quite figure out what is wrong, or where the error is, so after having narrowed it down as much as I can, this is what is necessary to replicate exactly the behavior I'm having trouble with. It's only the model, the context, the controller, and startup. It's mainly included to show that there's nothing (I consider) incredibly stupid being done in the model or anything, and at first I thought it might be the lazyloading, which is in startup, so it might be relevant.

Comment: @Dai, what's a *petulant* object?

Comment: Nothing in particular - it just means _misbehaving_, I'm just using colourful language to talk-smack about EF.

Comment: I see you're using EF classes as JSON DTOs. **Don't do that**. You need to define separate classes for EF entities and DTOs.

Comment: @Dai Meaning that the model used against the database and the ones returned by the controller should be two separate classes, containing basically the same thing? If I understand you correctly?

Comment: Correct. And while that _does_ sound tedious, it's necessary for too many reasons to list. Unfortunately there's a lot of "getting started" examples that do-it-all-wrong, ugh.

Comment: But there's plenty of tooling available to generate DTO types from EF classes.

Comment: @Dai "Don't do that" is a valid answer, and supporting it with reasons would be interesting and valuable. The only actual reasons I know of to separate the EF entity and DTO are that it's very common to not want to expose all the properties of the entity, and separating them from the start lets you refactor them independently.

Comment: @TechInquisitor API Versioning should be kept separate from EF/DB design changes. JSON-serialization traversing lazily-loaded navigation properties causing a stack-overflow exception. EF entities generally map 1:1 to tables but JSON DTOs are entirely freeform and should better represent your actual domain model. JSON DTOs should be entirely immutable whereas EF entities have to be mutable. Different validation rules for request-DTOs vs. internal entity classes, the list goes on...